# Torrent download

Tags: download, bittorrent

If I download legal content through a torrent, will it show the details of what I'm downloading in the office server? In general, if I surf the internet, it will list the website addresses that I visited in the server. If I download using a torrent, will show what I'm downloading?

If yes, how can I prevent that?

Comment: Assuming that these are legal videos, what is your real concern?

Comment: Please read [help] . Please realise we don't email people. And more importantly, don't abuse company resources by torrenting.

Comment: The million silly connections probably will red-flag your traffic. Don't you have useful work you should be doing?

Comment: @user256543 - The only thing your IT staff will know is that your using Peer to Peer software and are very likely using alot of bandwidth.  They would have to use deep packet inspection to know what your downloading.

Comment: They probably care less what you're downloading, but if there's a company internet abuse policy, the peer-to-peer and excessive bandwidth are inviting an HR review and a pink slip justified by the abuse of company owned connections and property.

Answer (score 2):

In General the Download usage will be filed/logged in server, The Size of file which you download on client machine will help your admin to catch you, You didn't mention what operating system was used on your server.

If it's windows machine there were many free bandwidth tools like [networx](http://www.softperfect.com/products/networx/) will help your admin to monitor your download usage from torrent sites and bit torrents

if it's linux machine there were possibilities to log your activities through squid logs,Apart from that if your connection is WAN or LAN,Tools like  [PRTG](http://www.paessler.com/prtg) or [MRTG](http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/) might be used  to  monitor the usage on the WAN and possibly LAN ports.

Answer (score -1):

If they can see the web traffic, that does not necessarily mean that they can also see other types of traffic. For example, regular web traffic might be clear to them, but secure traffic (https) might not. it really depends on what type of monitoring they have.

they might be monitoring the actual web browser. in which case, they will see the sites that you visit, but probably won't see the content (usernames, passwords, account numbers...)

They might be monitoring the network through a simple tap. This would allow them to see the plain text traffic. Eg. you might be able to see someone browsing `regularstuff.com` but now `https://regularstuff.com` This method often also would allow them to click on one traffic stream and select that traffic stream. Often enabling quite impressive tasks such as telling it to reconstructtt a web page as you saw it, or recreate the file that you downloaded from the raw traffic that you have downloaded. This is not always the case, but is a possibility. The best way to avoid something like this is a traffic anonimizer like tor or a VPN. (Be aware that this solution is quite possibly against the `Fair Computer Use` or some similar policy. They do have a right to understand what is being done with their computers and this hides that from them)

A third possible method of interception is a proxy server. It depends how much they proxy as to how much they would know. It would apparently proxy at least http traffic in your case, most likely https as well. This would basically mean that when you computer asked for `randomstuff.com/index.html` one of your companies servers says "Oh yeah, thats me!" and then goes and gets the real page and sends it back to you. This scary/annoying part of this is that it reveals the https traffic to them. Eg. You ask for `https://randomstuff.com/securepage.html` and your companies server responds to you and gets the real page and sends it to you. This would still protect you from the passive sniffing attacks mentioned in the previous paragraph, because your connection to your co's server is secure and the co's connection to the site is still secure, it just reveals it to the company. It is also possible that, depending on what settings they have configured, that your bittorent/other torrent client would default to using the proxy server they have set

---

All of this is very much speculation. It could be configured a thousand different ways. Most times they have a policy that explains what you are allowed to use the companies computers or internet for. You want to make sure that you follow all of their policies or risk being fired. This normally includes some form of "don't do illegal things with our property," their property includes computers, internet connection, hard drive space..... They also usually have a policy outlining what they track/log. Sometimes it even spells out specifically how they monitor things.